# Calling a outer function from within a closure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have function defined as  main which has a function inside say hit()

```
(function main(){

 var player1=new player();

 function hit(){
    //some code
 }
})();
```

This belongs to file main.js

I have another function player() in player.js which is called using the constructor at main.js

```
function player(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
            hit(); //cannot call hit
        }, 1500);
}
```

I want to call the hit() function in main.js from player.js, but I cannot do so as I get a undefined error.
 Isn't main.js completely accessible from player.js due to closure property

The way I include this files is:

```
<script src='player.js'></script>
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: `hit` is *scoped* locally to `main`. It doesn't have much to do with closures, just with *variable scope*. No, you cannot access it from outside; you'll have to `return` the function or otherwise make it available on the global scope or some other shared scope.

Comment: wont' having something like this.hit=hit in main.js make it accesible to player object?

Answer (score 0):

`hit` won't be accessible outside the closure. If you want it to expose globally , you will have to do something like:

```
//get hold of the global object
var global= (function(){
    return this;
})();

(function main(){
     var player1=new player();
     global.hit= function(){
        //some code
     };
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did and it seem to work for me

```
var mainObj=new main();

function main(){

 var player1=new player();
 var this.hit=hit;

 function hit(){
      //some code
 }
}

function player(){
    mainObj.hit();
}
```